# how to write a layout manager?

Tags: design-patterns, java-me, layout-manager

I'd like write a layout manager for j2me. I already have widgets and panels (panel is a set of widgets in this context). Now I'd like to add dynimc layout management so when i call doLayout on the outer most panel, internal widgets and panels rearrange according  device's width and height.

I was wondering whether there any well known patterns for layout managers.

Comment: Why are you writing your layout managers, you can use LWUIT. If you insist to write your own managers then take a look into LWUIT, it has many layout managers so you can start from one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each UI object should return a "minimum size (w,h)". Then you need an algorithm that traverse all your objects and split the available area in chunks and assign each chunk to an object.
You can Tree-Partition it based on the object relevance.

Comment: Yep. That's an idea. Right now my algorithm traverses the whole tree collecting min size for each widget. Then it does a second pass which resize widgets based on available room and widget's properties (alignment and expandability). I was wondering whether I could do everything in a single pass.

Comment: I think the double pass is the best and cleanest method out there.

Answer (score 0):

Common approach which I know is to keep each Displayable in Stack collection, such that current panel/screen should always be on top of Stack. And when user press "back" button you just should pop previous screen/panel on top of Stack.

Example [can be found here](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/nongraphical/index.html)

Comment: Yep. But that does not handle different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience my layout managers have evolved to fit the platform (X11,VT100,Windows) and their characteristics. However I have found common characteristics. Here is a good read/starting point that incorporates design patterns into our GUI challenges.

Reference: [Layout Manager using Design Patterns](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~lank/CS349/W13/lectures/10.pdf)